# Script seems to be running before the page loads

Tags: javascript

I have encountered a problem and couldn't yet find the solution that works. I have tried to add the if(okButton) condition before the `addEventListener` line, but still couldn't get the desired output. i.e the text that is being pointed to by the variable para doesn't disappear.

```
let para = document.getElementById('paragraph');
let okButton = document.getElementById('Ok-button');

okButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    para.style.display='none';
});
```

The error message is as follows:

> script.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'addEventListener' of 
>       null at VM2610 script.js:4(anonymous) @ script.js:4

Comment: load your js file after your paragraph and button.

Comment: do check the id because they are case sensitive too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible reasons:

- Your elements are below your javaScript.
- Your button id is "ok-button" but you have used "Ok-button". Id's are case sensitive. ( in the context of DOM and JS )

Comment: Thanks bro. The elements were indeed below the script tag and the case sensitivity was also the issue. Thanks a ton, again :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume your script is at the top of your file. So if you think of it as the file loads from top down okButton was not found because the rest of the page (DOM) did not load at the time you set okButton. Move the script to the bottom of the file or put it inside an init() on page load function, that way once the page has fully loaded you will set the okButton and it will exist on the page.

Comment: Helps fix the issue. Also, I had used "ok-button" as the id on my HTML page. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try add an If statement before the code for the button,

```
var Ok-button = document.getElementById("Ok-button");
if (Ok-button.clicked == true) {
            para.style.display='none';
}
```

Comment: Nope, you are wrong. You have function() {} inside addEventListener(). Check again.

Comment: Try that, i thing i have fund the solution.

Comment: The OP's code is fine he just loaded the script before his DOM or his button id is mismatched because DOM id is case sensitive. Solution must be according to the OP's code. There are many ways to achieve this. Anyways variable name cannot use hyphens because hyphen is operator.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a few comments, the elements that I used in the .js file were declared below the script tag in my HTML document. Moving the script tag just above the closing body tag fixed the issue.